# How to draw changing graph and its history below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, graph, d3.js

I need to draw spectrum graph and below - its history as a colored waterfall. Every second I redraw graph and it appears below as a colored line 1 pixel height. How can I draw bottom graph with d3.js?

[image]

Comment: Ok, I`ve changed to use d3.js. I can`t find, how to transfer top data to bottom graph as a colored line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 is a comprehensive library see the examples something might fit what you need.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

Comment: Thanks. Well, it`s a huge library. If I found answer, I`ll upvote.